# Finding the limit function of $f_n(x) = n^a x e^{-nx}$ defined in the section $\{0,1\}$...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So the question in itself is the title with the fact that we need to find:
$$ f(x) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) $$ in dependence on the paramater $a$

I have a hunch that the result is $0$ but i just cant seem to really prove it properly.
I always get stuck because I am not sure how to use the dependence of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\le 0$, then obviously $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} f_n (x)=0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. Now, suppose $a>0$. By L'Hospital's Rule

\begin{align}\lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{y^{a}}{e^{xy}}&=\lim_{y \to \infty} \left (\dfrac{\left ( \dfrac{d}{dy} \right )^{(\lfloor a\rfloor+1)}y^{a}}{\left ( \dfrac{d}{dy} \right )^{(\lfloor a\rfloor+1)}e^{xy}}\right )\\\\ &=\lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{\prod \limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor a \rfloor}(a-i)}{x^{\lfloor a\rfloor+1}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{y^{\lfloor a \rfloor+1-a}e^{xy}}\\ &=0\end{align}

Comment: shouldn't there be $y^ax$ in the first part of the formula?

Comment: it doesn't matter. Since we are analysing a limit when $y$ goes to $\infty$, $x$ is only a constant.

Comment: okay I get that, but if he is between 0 and 1, because he is considered a constant we dont have to look at him as if he can aspire to be 0 and then mess our calculations since we are working with $n$ and $a$?

Comment: what? I don't understand your question. Remember that $x \cdot 0 = 0$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: \begin{align}\lim_{y \to \infty} x \cdot \dfrac{y^{a}}{e^{xy}}&= x \cdot \lim_{y \to \infty}  \dfrac{y^{a}}{e^{xy}}=0\end{align}

Comment: ye never mind I got it in the end, I was confused with definitions and mixed it all up, thanks a lot!

Comment: :) you're welcome

Comment: Can't use LHR if $x=0.$

Comment: For $x=0$ the limit is obviously $0$